# Hadoop Map-reduce programming syntax error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My input is many text files. I want my map-reduce program to write all the files-names and the associated sentences with the file names in one output file, where I want to just emit the file-name(key) and the associated sentences(value) from the mapper. The reducer will collect the key and all the values and write the file-name and their associated sentences in the output.

Here is the code of my mapper and reducer:

```
import java.io.IOException;

   import java.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
   import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;


      public class WordCount {

public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,   
    Text, Text, Text> {



  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,Text> 
      output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
  String filename = new String();
  FileSplit filesplit = (FileSplit)reporter.getInputSplit();
  filename=filesplit.getPath().getName();
      output.collect(new Text(filename), value);


     }

    }


    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text,  
    Text, Text> {

     public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, 
         Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(Text value : values)
    {
        String str = value.toString();
        builder.append(str);
    }
    String valueToWrite=builder.toString();
    output.collect(key, new Text(valueToWrite));
      }

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text arg0, Iterator<Text> arg1,
            OutputCollector<Text, Text> arg2, Reporter arg3)
            throws IOException {
                    }




  }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
  conf.setJobName("wordcount");

  conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
  conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
  conf.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
  conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

  conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
  conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
  conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);
  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

  JobClient.runJob(conf);

 }
 }
```

The Output Terminal is as follows

```
 14/03/21 00:38:27 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library   
  for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
  14/03/21 00:38:27 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the 
 arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
14/03/21 00:38:27 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not  
be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
14/03/21 00:38:27 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : 
org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@4911b910
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
14/03/21 00:38:27 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And  
is in the process of commiting
14/03/21 00:38:28 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:  
file:/root/Desktop/wordcount/sample.txt:0+5371
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin :  
org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@1f8166e5
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
14/03/21 00:38:30 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000001_0 is done. And      
is in the process of commiting
14/03/21 00:38:31 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:  
file:/root/Desktop/wordcount/sample.txt~:0+587
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000001_0' done.
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : 
org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@3963b3e
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 2 sorted segments
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments  
left of total size: 7549 bytes
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And  
is in the process of commiting
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to 
commit now
14/03/21 00:38:33 INFO mapred.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task  
'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' to file:/root/Desktop/wordcount/output
14/03/21 00:38:36 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
14/03/21 00:38:36 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' done.
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 21
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=5958
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=8
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=26020
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=117337
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=7557
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=122
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=244
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=7301
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage  
(bytes)=954925056
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=5958
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=185
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=0
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=2
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=0
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
14/03/21 00:38:37 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=122
```

When I run the above mapper and reducer with the same configuration of inputformat (keyvaluetextinputformat.class) it does not write any thing in the output..

What should I change to achieve my goal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I look at the counters I see that the reducer has no input records.  That means something happened on the reducer side.

Looking at your code, I see that your reduce() method signature is:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, 
     Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
```

And that it declares values to be an Iterable.  The correct type is Iterator (according to the online Javadoc):

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, 
     Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
```

So even though you supplied a reduce method, the fact that is has the wrong signature means that it wasn't used.

Change the Iterable to Iterator and it should work

Comment: That is why everybody should add the `@Override` annotation :)

Comment: sir if i want to use iterable, then what would I do?

Comment: The only thing you can do with an Iterable is ask it for an iterator, so even if you managed to pass an Iterable in to your reduce method you'd have to write your code to access the values via an Iterator anyway.

Comment: sir whats the difference between iterator and iterable?

Comment: An iterator is something that lets you traverse a list, front first to last, without having to know the implementation or even location of the list.  An iterable is something that can be iterated, but it's only documented behavior is the ability to return an iterator that lets you do the actual iterating.  There is is no other action that you can take against the iterable, unless of course you know the actual class of the object or know another interface that the class implements.  Only then can you perform some other behavior against an iterable.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, After a long struggle I got my correct output.